# Identify SQL Query

Tags: java, sql

I am having a requirement in which I need to identify the type of SQL Query and execute it using JDBC. As SQL query will be provided at runtime so I just want to know that is there any criteria to find out whether the query is of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or SELECT.

Currently I implemented it with comparing the starting query text with INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or SELECT.

```
          try {                 
                if (querytext.startsWith("insert")
                        || querytext.startsWith("INSERT")) {
                    // insert operation                     
                } else if (querytext.startsWith("update")
                        || querytext.startsWith("UPDATE")
                        || querytext.startsWith("delete")
                        || querytext.startsWith("DELETE")) {
                    // update operation
                } else {
                    // select operation
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: Does your SQL backend support the syntax: SELECT * INTO... Have oy considered that? Besides that. executing user input on a SQL database can get very dangerous very quickly.

Comment: @HyperLink i dnt think so, you can except using `indexOf`, or String functions etc.

Comment: @steenbergh yeah that case is excluded for the time being.

Comment: @POHH I think that was clear enough, you uselessly mark it down.

Comment: hey buddy i have not mark it down... someone else does. just didnt get you explaination thats why asking

Comment: @ankur-singhal I didn't get what you want to say?

Comment: @HyperLink i mean as you are comparing currently the first word, except that i cannot think of any other solution.

Comment: Maybe too much, but have a look at this site http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Joachim thanks but it only validate the syntax and not the schema related things. For that we need to hit DB only. I explored it already.

Comment: What about a common table expression that starts with `WITH`? That could be an insert, update, delete or a plain select. Your `else` branch would also treat `drop` or `create` as a "select"

Answer (score 0):

Some vendors support IF statements. For example in SQL server you can do:

IF Exists (Select * from test)
select * from test

or

IF Exists  (Select * from test)
insert into test  values (1,2,3)

Also many languages support common table expressions that begin with "with". This can be used for inserts  and updates.
Standard SQL supports a MERGE statement.  And other vendors  support varying kinds of updates like  UPSERT, REPLACE, ..

Answer (score 0):

@HyberLink I don't understand your requirement exactly. At least **(Update/Delete/Insert) or (Select)** is somehow acceptable.. But grouping all together is not a great idea. But since its a requirement, its hard to decide good or bad on your own. So assuming you want a solution to check before making a JDBC call !! Well you got two choices..

- Use `String.indexOf()`
- Don't use the first , because at times even `INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE` all can have a `SELECT` ***(sub queries ?)*** . So its not just about,`INSERT into <table_name> VALUES(SELECT <fields> from <some_other_table>)`. Be prepared with all sort of expected queries and choose a wise choice **(So, if you have nothing to worry about the monsters i mentioned above, then the first choice itself a good deal.)**